# Why is Kafka considered more stable than REST?

Tags: rest, http, apache-kafka

Why is Kafka considered more stable in comparison to REST, isn't the concept of REST responses the same as the acknowledgement concept in Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Kafka accepts messages independently from any business logic. Data you send to Kafka (eventually) has to conform to a specific schema, which is similar to schema validation for most RESTful interfaces, but that is all.

However, calling a REST endpoint, there are many reasons for a request to return !=200 code, ergo non-success. It's not just about availability, but also invalid permissions, invalid operations, semantically wrong requests (trying to change an object that does not exist), throttling / rate limiting, long processing time and timeouts for expensive processing on backend side. To avoid data loss, all of these cases need to be handled by retries, which might lead to a blocking behaviour.

Kafka helps in decoupling the delivery of data from performing business logic or persisting data. If the backend is under load, the message delivery will not block and create back pressure, but rather messages will get queued in a Kafka topic. Issues can be solved independently from a producer and the actual processing (or delivery to RESTful endpoint) can be managed by a consumer in a more controlled fashion.

It's basically the difference of synchronous vs asychronous interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka's ack are producer-side configuration. When you want to send data to Kafka you can have

- No ack: Data are written to Kafka but, Kafka does not give any acknowledgement back. In the case of Kafka broker down, data can be lost and you won't know about it.
- Leader ack: As soon as data is written to the Leader node in Kafka, Kafka sends back an acknowledgement. There might not be replication. But data is safer.
- All ack: Kafka sends back acknowledgement only after data gets written to all the nodes.

Kafka's ack does not **work on HTTP and it has its own binary TCP mechanism**.

However, the REST response(I am guessing you are talking about HTTP status codes) is a way to give back ack in traditional client-server architecture. This means the server decides how it wants to process your request and sends a response.

In my opinion, it is not correct to say Kafka's ack is more stable. It's different in flavour than REST APIs.